# Showing a function is continuous using the definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I would really like some help in proving that the following two functions are continuous using the definition of continuity.

> Show that $f(x) = x^2$  and $g(x) = \cos(x)$ are continuous on $I = [0, \frac\pi2]$

Thank you!

Comment: @Maadhav nothing really. I am way more comfortable showing that functions are continuous at a point and I really have no clue how to show they are continuous on a set.

Comment: Showing continuity on a set means showing continuity at every point taken from the set.

Comment: @MichelleDrolet It just means that it is continuous at each point of the set.

Comment: For Cosine, you can take a look on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875145/exactly-how-does-this-proof-mean-that-the-cosine-function-is-continuous

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, showing that a function is continuous on a set is showing that it is continuous in each element of that set.

As an example, I show you that $f$ is continuous on the given interval (note that we can give exactly the same proof to show the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$)

Let $a \in [0,\pi/2]$ be fixed but arbitrary.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta := \min\left\{\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}, \frac{\epsilon}{4(|a|+1)}\right\}$

Then, for all $x \in [0,\pi/2]$ such that $|x-a| <\delta$, we have:

$$|x^2 - a^2| = |x-a||x+a| = |x-a||x-a + 2a| \leq|x-a|(|x-a| + 2|a|) \leq \delta^2 + 2\delta|a|\leq \epsilon$$

Hence, $f$ is continuous at $a$ and because $a$ is arbitrary it follows that $f$ is continuous on $[0,\pi/2]$, as desired.

I leave the other one for you.